# NodeJs: can't write a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, node.js

I'm new in node, for practice i thought to develop a weather commandline application, but i found a problem with ajax request, i'm usually to use $.ajax of jquery but it doesn't works, ( I've tried to require jquery ). I've solved this problem with another module.

Now the problem is: when i try to print json information on the **coords.json** and next read it with **read-json** module there are some  "\" & "\n" everywhere in the string, i've tried to replace it with regex and **fs** module but it doesn't re-write the file... why?

Here the full code:

```
// index.js
// modules
const program = require('commander');
const clear = require('clear');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const request = require('ajax-request');
const fs = require('fs');

const json = require('read-data').json;
const writeJson = require('write-json');

// Forecast.io Key
const key = "*************";
const freegeoip = "http://freegeoip.net/json/";

let latitude = 0,
    longitude = 0 ;

// forecast.io api url
const url = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${key}/${latitude},${longitude}`;

// initialize myData with the freegeoip datas
let myData = request({
  url: 'http://freegeoip.net/json/',
  method: 'GET',
  data: {
     format: 'json'
  },
}, function(err, res, body) {
  writeJson('test.json', body, function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });
});

fs.readFile('test.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  let result = data.replace(/[\\~#%&*<>?|\-]/g, '');
    fs.writeFile('test.json', result, 'utf8', function (err) {
       if (err) return console.log(err);
       // if i do this is normal json
       // console.log(result)
    });

});
```

and the output in the file is:

```
// coords.json

"{\"ip\":\"**.**.**.**\",\"country_code\":\"IT\",\"country_name\":\"Italy\",\"region_code\":\"62\",\"region_name\":\"Latium\",\"city\":\"Rome\",\"zip_code\":\"00119\",\"time_zone\":\"Europe/Rome\",\"latitude\":**.*,\"longitude\":**.**\"metro_code\":0}\n"
```

but if i print it in console it's normal...

Comment: your code does nothing with `coords.json`

Comment: You have an async issue.  Your `fs.readFile()` is executed BEFORE your `writeJson()` function has finished.

Comment: Yes i know in this code coords not appear, test.json is the same file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really recommend that you use JSON.parse. It will parse your json and put it into a variable you can use:

```
fs.readFile('test.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {  
    data = JSON.parse(data); // Yay you can use anything from the JSON
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The \ are there to escape the quotes so that they don't end the string. They shouldn't affect anything, and are actually necessary. Have you tried it without the regex? That could be breaking things if it actually removes the .